# Validation of data with char

Tags: c, if-statement, char, int, do-while

I'm looking for a valid condition to check if the user is writing a char or not. I was trying with (n!=char), but this is clearly not possible in C right?

this is what I have:

```
char n;
do
{
    printf("Introduce a caracter\n");
    scanf("%c", &n);
    if(n!=char)
        printf("Error! The caracter you introduced is not valid.\n");
}
while(n!=char);

return n;
```

Comment: What kind of characters would you want to be valid?

Comment: Indeed this code won't work, since you cannot simply guess the C language syntax, you actually have to know it.

Comment: Every single character is valid, I don't want the user to input any integrer

Comment: Digits are characters, too.  Do you mean you want the user to input a *letter*?  Is a punctuation mark ok?  A control character?  Do you need to be able to accept space, tab, and/or newline characters?

Comment: I want the programm just accept letters A-Z, upper case or lower case

Answer (score 1):

As you only want letters, upper case or lower case, you can check it using this condition in the if statement.

```
if((n<'a' || 'z'<n) && (n<'A' || 'Z'<n))
    printf("Error! The caracter you introduced is not valid.\n");
```

This means:

if 'n' is not in the inverval of chars between 'a-z' AND not between 'A-Z', then ERROR

You can think of chars as integers stored considering de [ascii chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii).

Comment: I didn't know that I could do this in terms of chars, I hope it works, thank you!

Comment: @eventHandler : Shouldn't the 'or' statement be expressed as `||`?

Comment: @Gophyr you are right, i have eddited it. Thank you for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a distinction between a character and a non-character in this method, because you are reading into a character.  A character is simply an 8-bit integer, and it can be signed or unsigned, just as 8-bit integers can be (`int8_t`, `uint8_t`).  As such, you can say things like:

```
char c = 'A';
printf("%d %c\n", c, c);
```

This would print:

65 A

because A is represented by the decimal number 65, and %d` specifies that you wish to print a decimal integer.

If you want to differentiate between, say, the character 'A' and the character '4', then you would use something like eventHandler used here.  If you wished to count everything after 'A' as a character (this includes some of the characters like '[' and '_'), you would use something like:

```
if (n < 'A') {
  printf("ERROR: You did not enter a character.\n");
}
```

And as eventHandler also said, read an ascii chart.